# Mail app no longer automatically creates clickable hyperlinks when pasting a URL. How do I fix it?

Tags: macos, mail.app, mojave

Since recently the MacOS Mail app no longer automatically converts a URL (that I paste) into a clickable hyperlink. 
How do I fix this?

Working on MacOS Mojave 10.14.1 in Mail 12.1

Answer (score 8):

Acutally they just changed the default setting... In Mac Mail Just go to the menu "edit->subsistutions->smart links" and click on it if it's unchecked to active the feaure.

After that you can paste or type links and it will do the add link operation automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct - the render doesn't happen anymore while editing and I haven't seen a documented way to change that behavior.

I just save the mail as a draft then look at it in drafts or reopen it for editing.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem periodically. It goes on for a while and then stops mysteriously, but has not been solved by device restarts, etc. However, I tried @Scottalator's suggestion. "Smart links" was checked, but when I unchecked and re-checked it, that seemed to fix the problem.